# Measure elapsed time with a defer statement in Go

Tags: go, time, defer-keyword

I thought of using the `defer` statement to measure the elapsed time of a program in Go:

```
func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    defer fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("The process took %s", time.Now().Sub(start)))
    ...
}
```

I thought this would produce the correct result but it didn't:

```
[09:36:55]pc@work:~/test$ go run ./main.go
Processed 209806/209806 TUF files
All records are inserted in the database.
Verifying records are inserted correctly...
Verified 209806/209806 TUF files
All records have been inserted and verified successfully.
The process took 600ns
[14:24:06]pc@work:~/test$
```

Even though the process took 5 hours, which is visible from the timestamps on the left, the deferred `fmt.Println()` statement showed 600 nanoseconds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rather than `fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("<<format>>", args...))` it is more standard and compact to use `fmt.Printf("<<format>>\n", args...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defered function arguments are evaluated immediately. You can wrap their evaluation into an anonymous function to delay their evaluation until the defer actually gets triggered:

```golang
defer func() {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("The process took %s", time.Now().Sub(start)))
}()
```

Read more about the defer statement in [A Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/12) and the [language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements).

Answer (score 3):

The arguments to the `defer`red function are evaluated right away, meaning the `time.Now().Sub(start)` part is computed right after the start.

If you want to time the function, say:

```
defer func() {
    time.Now().Sub(start) // ...
}()
```

Alternatively, I have written a package for it: https://github.com/gonutz/tic so you can say:

```
func main() {
    defer tic.Toc()()
}
```

and note the two `()()` which are there for the exact same reason, the first function call starts the timing and returns a function to be deferred which stops the timing.